# How do I show a simple border around a UIElement when something is being dragged over

Tags: wpf

I have a UIElement over which users will be dragging stuff over and dropping to. I went through a few articles online on how to do the Drag and Drop in WPF but they are very sophisticated and most of them are designed to work together with Drag Source, require some canvas to draw the adorner image while source is being dragged over and require the behavior to be attached at the level of the Source.

My problem is a little different, I have a drop target and I have no idea where the source is. All I have to do is, when something is being dragged over, show the rectangle or border around my UIElement.

I tried to handle UIElement.DragEnter and changed the BorderBrush and Thickness but it did not help.

Is there any simple way of doing it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this small example. When i got your question right that is what you want to do?

The UIElement (in this case a listbox) sets the AllowDrop property to true (needed to receive the drag events at all).
In the DragEnter event i set the thickness to 10, in the dragleave back to zero.
It works as expected (i tried it with draging desktop icons over it)

```
<ListBox AllowDrop="True" Name="MBox" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0"  DragEnter="MBox_OnDragEnter" DragLeave="MBox_OnDragLeave"></ListBox>
```

```
private void MBox_OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    MBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(10);
}

private void MBox_OnDragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    MBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
}
```

If this answer does not fit your needs, show your not working code. Maybe that will help to find the issue.

Comment: Your code works. Turned out the problem was with the UIElement I was dropping stuff to. It was DevExpress' TextEdit which suppressed the borders and I had to use the Effect.

Comment: ah okay! yeah sometimes such custom controls are a bit tricky. would be nice if you mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)